# When to delete file shared with external apps by using Intent.ACTION_SEND in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, share

In my application i allow users to share files with external apps by using **Intent.ACTION_SEND**. My files are encrypted so before I can share one of those files, I need to decrypt it and store it in application internal storage. After that I share file Uri to send a file.**For security issues I would like to remove the file from internal storage after external application has used it, or user cancelled operation**.

**Brief** : in my project i decrypt the selected files and save in to internal storage location Temp folder/directory. after that generate arraylist of uris for that files and share arraylist of 'usri's.

here main problem is delete the temp folder after success/failure to share files.

I use below code for sharing files

```
private void startShareIntent(ArrayList<Uri> uris) {
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
    share.setType("audio/*");
    share.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share audio File(s)"),SHARE_AUDIO_FILES_CODE);
}
```

for getting onActivity result

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if(requestCode==SHARE_AUDIO_FILES_CODE)
        {
            //TODO delete decrypted files when success
         }
        }
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        //TODO delete decrypted files when failure.
    }
}
```

But here always resultCode return RESULT_CANCELED only. and its called before completed of sharing files.

Comment: hmmm do it in android way: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html

Comment: @Selvin Thanks for responce. in my project i decrypt the selected files and save in to internal storage location Temp folder/directory. after that generate arraylist of uris for that files and share arraylist of 'usri's.here main problem is delete the temp folder after success/failure to share files.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the file from sdcard on `onResume()` of your activity. So when the user ll press back from the external app, it will get closed and your app will get resumed from the same activity which opened it.

But i personally don't that that your approach is the best way to tackle security issues. Anyone with little knowledge will be able to copy the decrypted files while they are open.

Comment: Thanks for response. Here onResume() called when before files are uploading/sharing time. if i deleted decrypt files in onResume, it will shows to file not found exception.

Comment: You have to put a condition around this, in which case you want to do what in onResume itself.